# Why won't my csv list replace my blank values with "N"?

Tags: python-2.7, replace, readlines

I'm attempting to create a function which reads a specific column of a csv file which currently alternates between empty values and "1", pops them into a list and then replaces them with an "N" for the empty value and "B" for the "1"'s. I'm pretty new to python, as well as programming in general, so any tips and all help is welcome. This is what I have so far, and it does process, but only replaces my "1"'s with "B"'s. I've double checked my csv and the position is definitely empty and does not contain spaces. I've also looked at other responses and tried to emulate some similar logic that appeared to be behind them, but something still doesn't seem to work. If someone could point me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

```
#sample data (for 195 entries):    
["Header0,"Header1","Foundation","Header3"],
["abc1","a12n","","123"],
["def2","d13b","1","456"],
["ghi3","g12n","","789"],

def Foundation( csv_file_path, Remove_Header = False, Remove_SubHeader = False ):

delineator = ','

raw_file = file(csv_file_path, 'r')
return_List = []

n = 0

#Process lines in file
for line in raw_file.readlines():
    #Check if to include or remove header
    if (n == 0 ) and (Remove_Header == True):
        n = n + 1
        continue

    #Check if to include or remove sub header
    if (n == 1) and (Remove_SubHeader == True):
        n = n + 1
        continue

    sList2 = line.replace("\n","").strip().split( delineator )
    col_2 = str(sList2.pop(2))
    for n in col_2:
        if n == "1":
            col_2 = col_2.replace("1", "B")
        elif n == "":
            col_2 = col_2.replace("", "N")
    print col_2
    return_List.append(sList2) #add my secondary list back to my main List? right?

    sList2.insert(0, col_2)# insert back to my secondary list where it went
    n = n + 1 #add to counter and move down the line

raw_file.close()

#Return the list
return return_List
```

Comment: Could you please add the sample data and expected output?

Comment: Sample data would be ["","1","","1","".....] and so on, but for 195 entries. And expected output would be ["N","B","N","B","N"....] for each entry.